# How do I make my presentation widescreen in Google Drive?

Tags: google-slides

Google Drive just announced that they now support Widescreen formats and it is now default.  However how do you change existing projects settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply select `Slide` --> `Change Theme` and change the resolution in the bottom right.

[image: slide]

[image: change]